@FunctionalProtocols for Swift?
My Problem
I'm looking for a while for an equivalent of Javas @FunctionalInterface in Swift.
Swift is titled as Protocol-Oriented Programming Language and known for his Syntactic Sugar. So I hope anyone got an idea to implement what I'm looking for.
The Reason I want this, is to create swifty on-the-Fly implementations of a protocol in Swift, which should be behave like a normal Protocol conform data type. This should be able to be initialised with an closure which represent the only one method which is in the Protocol declared. Currently the Java way is more swifty than the Swift once.
I also read this Treads:

How use closures in swift like Java interfaces

Swift 5.9 brought us macros, I hope this can be a way to do this, but I'm currently not familiar with this.
My Question

Does anyone know a way to implement this as a Swift Macro or something similar?

Here is the current way to go in Swift
protocol ArgumentChecker {
  func check(arguments: [String]) -> Bool
}

struct ClosureArgumentChecker: ArgumentChecker { /// What I want to hide
  let closure: ([String]) -> Bool

  func check(arguments: [String]) -> Bool {
    return closure(arguments)
  }
}

let checker: ArgumentChecker = ClosureArgumentChecker(closure: { arguments in
  return arguments.isEmpty
})

func main() {
  if !(checker is ArgumentChecker) {
    return
  }

  print("checker is an instance of ArgumentChecker")
  let result = checker.check(arguments: CommandLine.arguments)
  print("Result from checker: \(result)")
}

main()


Here is a working Java equivalent
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ArgumentChecker {
    boolean check(final String[] args);

    ArgumentChecker checker = (final String[] arguments) -> arguments.length == 0;

    static void main(final String[] args) {
        if(!(checker instanceof ArgumentChecker)) {
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("checker is an instance of ArgumentChecker");
        final boolean result = checker.check(args);
        System.out.println("Result from checker: " + result);

    }
}

Here is my exception / idea how should it look like
import Foundation

protocol ArgumentChecker {
    func check(args: [String]) -> Bool
} 

@functionalProtocol
let checker: ArgumentChecker = { (args: [String]) -> Bool in
    args.isEmpty
}


func main() {
    guard !(checker is ArgumentChecker) else {
        print("checker is not an ArgumentChecker")
        return
    }
        
    print("checker is an ArgumentChecker")

    let args = ["Hello", "World"]
    let result = checker.check(args)
    print("Result: \(result)")
}

Thanks for any response.

Why not just use a ([String]) -> Bool closure directly? Why wrap it in a protocol? You can also add a type alias if you want a better name for it. Java's functional interfaces exists only because Java doesn't have proper function types like Swift does.

Why do you want to hide ClosureArgumentChecker anyway? Swift being a "Protocol-Oriented Programming Language" doesn't mean you should replace function types with protocools.

@Sweeper, you're right, I had a wrong idea about the interface that both types share.

This is what I actually wanted. Thanks to @Sweeper at this point.
/// verbose why
protocol ArgumentChecker {
  var action: ([String]) -> Bool { get }
}

struct ClosureArgumentChecker: ArgumentChecker {
  let action = { (args: [String]) -> Bool in
      return args.isEmpty
  }
}

/// short why
let onTheFlyChecker = { (args: [String]) -> Bool in
    return args.isEmpty
}

func executeClosure(closure: ([String]) -> Bool) -> Bool {
    let input = CommandLine.arguments
    return closure(input)
}

func main() {
    /// verbose why
    let checker = ClosureArgumentChecker()
    let result = executeClosure(closure: checker.action)
    print("Result from checker: \(result)")
    
    /// short why
    let result2 = executeClosure(closure: onTheFlyChecker)
    print("Result from onTheFlyChecker: \(result2)")
  
    /// Or this why
    let result3 = executeClosure { (args: [String]) -> Bool in
        return args.isEmpty
    }
    print("Result from onTheFlyChecker: \(result3)")
}

main()


